# HTML/CSS: scroll div without setting position to fixed or absolute

Tags: html, css

so I have the following problem: I want to add a sidebar with a lot of content to my webpage. So the sidebar (div) should be scrollable and should also hide upon click. 
To the right of the sidebar is my content. The content should always be to the right of the sidebar and the sidebar should never overlay parts of the content.

Here's my css:

```
div.sidebar {
    position: fixed; 
    float:left;
    left:0rem;
    top:0rem;
    bottom:1.2rem;
    width:21rem;
    background-color:rgb(110, 110, 110);
    z-index:999;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
div.content {
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 2em;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 180%;
    line-height: 130%;
}
```

If the css is like that with position:fixed (or absolute) the sidebar is scrollable and the body does not scroll. But the sidebar hides parts of the content. 
If I remove the "position:fixed" from the .sidebar the content aligns right of the sidebar but the sidebar is not scrollable anymore (now the whole page has a scrollbar). 
Specifying overflow: hidden for the body of the page didn't help. Neither did removing any of the left, top, bottom, float etc. tags. What am I missing?

How can I achieve a sidebar that is scrollable but does not overlay the content. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is that what you want to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/z8dqhrf2/ ?

Comment: thank you @Kocik for your comment. That's what it should look like if the sidebar is expanded yes. But I'd like the content to take up all the screen if the sidebar is hidden. look at [this](http://themetrust.com/demos/port/) example, how the text moves a bit to the left if the sidebar is expanded..

Comment: Not possible without JS.

Comment: @Mohammed Hâmzã I highly doubt that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution for you:

Wrap contents of sidebar into second div and add some class attribute - .fixed in my example. Now, we make .fixed div fixed, .sidebar div will take the space, so .content won't be overlapped by .fixed. Remember to set the same width for .fixed and .content, so they take the same space . Now, set `width: auto` in .content div, so it take all the space and `overflow: hidden`.

Now, when .sidebar has `display: none`, fixed will be hidden, and .content will take all their space :D

CSS:

```
div.sidebar {
    /* take space on the left */
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin-bottom:100%;

    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div.fixed {
    /* display fixed menu */
    position:fixed;
    width:20%;

    left:0rem;
    top:0rem;
    bottom:1.2rem;
    z-index:999;
    rgb(110, 110, 110)
    overflow-y:scroll;

}
div.content {
    width:auto; /* take all the space */
    overflow:hidden; /* try using without it and see what happens ;) */

    border-width: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 180%;
    line-height: 130%;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/z8dqhrf2/2/

Comment: That did work! Thank you so much! I spent hours today trying to get that to work. SO is awesome. Cheers!

Comment: quick follow up, @Kocik . In your jsfiddle as well as on my page the body gets an unnecessary scrollbar. Do you know how i can avoid that? I can't set overflow:hidden because I have certain pages where a scrollbar is necessary...

Comment: If you check elements properties (in Chrome: r-click>Inspect element) you will see, that .sidebar `margin-bottom:100%` is just too long. You can change it to e.g. `height: 1px` or `margin-bottom: 1px` and should be ok :)